# What is the opposite of signee?

Tags: meaning

Signee is the person who signs the contract, but what is the word for the person who gave the signee the contract in order to have it signed.
For instance, if someone asks you to sign a confidentiality agreement you are the signee and the other person is the ...?
Signor doesnt sound like the right word...

Comment: *Signee*, if it existed, would refer to the contract itself.

Comment: The person who signs a contract is the **signer**, not the Singee.

Comment: [Signee](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/signee) is someone who signs a contract. So is signatory and signer. I rather think the "opposite" very much depends upon the particular situation.

Answer (score 2):

Although the word 'signee' is listed in some dictionaries, the normal word for a person who signs a document is 'signatory'. **All** the parties who sign are signatories.